# How to intentionally break a codeship build?

Tags: continuous-integration, codeship

I've written a test script I want to run in my setup commands of my codeship build. If it fails, I want it to cause the whole build to fail, which is normal behavior for things like unit tests.

In Travis CI, this seems [well documented](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Breaking-the-Build):

> If any of the commands in the first four stages of the build lifecycle return a non-zero exit code, the build is broken

**How can I accomplish this same behavior in codeship?** I tried exiting my script with code 1, but the code ship kept right on a-sailin'.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://documentation.codeship.com/faq/run-command-if-other-fails/

Answer (score 2):

Exiting with code 1 *does* cause the build to fail, but only in the "test commands" or "test pipeline" box.

I had been incorrectly running tests in the "setup commands" box.

Now this final line in my python testing suite has the right behavior in codeship:

```
sys.exit(0 if success else 1)
```

Comment: Any non-zero exit code should mark the build as failed, even if you run that command via the setup commands. I realize this answer is a (tiny) bit late, but if this still occurs, please let us know via a ticket.